# ORDER BY with two criteria in a CASE expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-order-by, switch-statement

I have a select statement where I want to order by different criteria based on a CASE expression, but I'm having trouble with syntax when I want to order by multiple criteria. I would like it to be similar to the following code, but I get syntax errors.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 1 THEN Column1, Column2 END,
CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 2 THEN Column3 END,
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although a `case` only returns one value, you can repeat the case:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 1 THEN Column1
               WHEN @OrderBy = 2 THEN Column3
          end),
         (CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 1 THEN Column2 END)
```

This gives the secondary sort on `Column2` for `@OrderBy = 1`.

In fact, this will also work and it might be closer to what you were originally thinking:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 1 THEN Column1 end),
         (CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 1 THEN Column2 end),
         (CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 2 THEN Column3 end)
```

In this version, the first two clauses will return `NULL` for all rows for the value of 2.  Then the third row will be invoked for the sort.

Answer (score 4):

`CASE` is an *expression* which returns *exactly* one result, and cannot be used for control-of-flow logic like in some other languages. I have no idea what your data types are so I'm guessing you want this:

```
CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 1 THEN Column1 END,
CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 2 THEN Column3 END,
Column2;
```

If Column1 and Column3 have the same (or compatible) data types, you can simplify:

```
CASE @OrderBy 
  WHEN 1 THEN Column1
  WHEN 2 THEN Column3 END,
Column2;
```

You can just add Column2 to the end because it doesn't need a conditional - it's 2nd for the first condition and if you only care about Column3 for the second condition, it probably doesn't matter that you also order by Column2.

Answer (score 2):

Generate ORDER BY CLAUSE on client, or use DYNAMIC SQL

For Example:

```
 DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(1000)
  SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM Table1 {order}';
  SET @sql = CASE WHEN @orderBY = 1 THEN REPLACE(@sql, '{order}', 'ORDER BY column1, column2')
                  WHEN @orderBY = 2 THEN REPLACE(@sql, '{order}', 'ORDER BY column3')
             END
  -- by default value replace {order} to empty string
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 1 THEN Column1 else Column3 END,
Column2
```

Comment: This only works if Column1 and Column3 have compatible data types.

Comment: Agreed, but hopefully the original poster understands `CAST` and/or `CONVERT`.

Comment: I'm just saying that, as written, it may come back with a data type conversion error. It is usually useful to post such a disclaimer up front rather than just assuming the OP will understand what to do...